# I cannot close my scanner

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I have had a look around and I cannot seem to find the answer to this. I created a program that inputs a number corresponding to a chess board and gives an answer all the way up to a maximum number that makes it print an error report. I cannot work out a way to close my scanner. I am very new to java and need some help with my code:

```
while (true) {  

//learned the import scanner from Greg and managed to get it working with my code :) 
System.out.println("Please select chess square from 1 - 25");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
final int SIZE = 5;
//the plus one makes it start in the correct point
int SQUARENUM = scan.nextInt()+1; 

int grains = 1; 
int j = 1;
int tGrains = 0;


if (SQUARENUM > 26){
    System.out.println("****************---------------****************");
    System.out.println("** ERROR Only 25 squares to choose from ERROR **");
    System.out.println("****************---------------****************");

    continue;}

//still trying to get it to close without the error. 
//if(scan!=null)
//scan.close();


System.out.println("The amount of squares on the 5 by 5 board is: " + (SIZE*SIZE));
System.out.println("Looking at Square:"+(SQUARENUM - 1));

while(j < SQUARENUM){           
    System.out.println("Grains of wheat on square:" + j + " is:" + grains);
    grains *= 2; 
    tGrains = tGrains + grains;
    j++;        
}
System.out.println(" *** Total Grains of Wheat = " + (tGrains/  2) + " ***");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first iteration of the loop will be fine and you will be able to do

```
scan.close();
```

The problem is when the loop go to the second iteration. And you call

```
scan.nextInt();
```

After you **closed** the scanner. You can not use the scanner again after closing it.
So you should move `scan.close()` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

To close a `Scanner` call [`close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29) after you have finished using it.

In general you should access your scanner in a try-catch-finally block and close the Scanner in the finally block to ensure that it always closes.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) for a tutorial on using `Scanner`

You might also want to check out the [try with resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) feature in Java 7.

Comment: It's right to use try-catch to close the scanner but that is not the source of his problem since you can use `close()` without a try block.